# azure adl json files u-Sql error: 'Extract' on the user type 'Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.MultiLevelJsonExtractor'

Tags: json, azure-data-lake, u-sql, argument-dependent-lookup

When I try to extract from json files I get the error:

> adl An unhandled exception from user code has been reported when invoking the method 'Extract' on the user type 'Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.MultiLevelJsonExtractor'

I have installed assembly but i'm always getting this error when I try doing jobs on .json files.

Here is my code:

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY BankingADLDB.[Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY BankingADLDB.[Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats]; 

USING Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json;

DECLARE @in string=@"adl://xxx.azuredatalakestore.net/14-04-2018/00_0_18144c820d664dfea18583f9ce515bd3.json";
DECLARE @out string=@"Test.csv";

@result =
     EXTRACT message string,
             messageTypeId string,
             providerTypeId string,
             identifier string,
             key string,
             extras string
     FROM @in
     USING new MultiLevelJsonExtractor("TranscriptionSections[*].Sentences[*]",
           false,
           "message",
           "messageTypeId",
           "providerTypeId",
           "identifier",
           "key",
           "extras");         

OUTPUT @result
TO @out 
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Here is a sample of the json file:

{"solution":"poo","message":{"messageTypeId":1,"providerTypeId":1,"identifier":"1-7jh88","entries":[{"key":"userinfo","value":{"name":"John Jo Carvalho","gender":"unknown","birthDate":"","nif":"","email":"sample@sample.me","phoneNumber":"+351789582471","userLocation":{"address":"","town":"Lisbon","postalCode":"","country":"Portugal"},"photoUrl":"https://xxx.jpg"}}],"extras":[]},"EventProcessedUtcTime":"2018-04-14T00:00:19.2501003Z","PartitionId":1,"EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2018-04-14T00:00:19.1970000Z","IoTHub":{"MessageId":null,"CorrelationId":null,"ConnectionDeviceId":"1-7jh88","ConnectionDeviceGenerationId":"123456789123456789","EnqueuedTime":"2018-04-14T00:00:19.0120000Z","StreamId":null}}

Comment: Can you provide some sample (anonymised if necessary) json please?

Comment: Yes @wBob there you have it

Comment: Also can you provide the rest of the error message. Normally there is more detail that will tell you what error occurred.

Comment: This json bears no resemblance to the json you are trying to shred in your code.  For example, your sampe json does not contain `Sentences` ndoes in a parent `TranscriptionSections` node.  Please provide some json which accurately reflects your real json.

Answer (score 0):

For the actual json you have provided, I was able to make this work with a slightly different json path, ie `messages.entries[*]`:

```
@result =
     EXTRACT 
//            message string,
             messageTypeId string,
             providerTypeId string,
             identifier string,
             key string,
             extras string
     FROM @in
     //USING new MultiLevelJsonExtractor("TranscriptionSections[*].Sentences[*]",
     USING new MultiLevelJsonExtractor("message.entries[*]",
             true,
//           "message",
           "messageTypeId",
           "providerTypeId",
           "identifier",
           "key",
           "extras");
```

I've removed the `message` column from the `EXTRACT` statement as in json terms it is an object, containing other items.

My results:

[image: My Results]